# Obtaining Google Chrome mobile browser 'omnibox' height

Tags: google-chrome, responsive-design, google-chrome-devtools, mobile-website

I am remote debugging on Android with Chrome (dev) version 49.0.2623.0. Specifically, I'm screencasting.

How do I find the height of the transparent area at the top of my Chrome screencast, which is occupied by my test device's mobile Chrome browser 'omnibox' (the checkerboard area in the attached image, below)?

Alternatively, how can I design my mobile responsive layouts to account for the height of mobile browser address or nav bars?

[image: Chrome Canary Android mobile screencast snapshot]

Comment: What exactly do you think about your application should change based on the height of the omnibar (which may also gets hidden in some circumstances)?

Comment: I want to plan the vertical layout of the application and without the omnibar height I cannot reliably do so.